# set the rootViewController = UITabBarController() will trigger offScreen-rendered?

Tags: ios

When I set `therootViewController = UITabbarController()` or it's subclass in the appdelegate, and I discovered it will trigger the offScreen-rendered in the simulator.

But when I set `rootViewController = UIViewController()`, it won't trigger it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is? Are you asking why this is? Or do you want to do something? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: eh,sorry,i just wanna ask why.sorry that i haven't expressed what i want

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController will trigger offscreen render when translucent is YES, You can set translucent to NO to avoid offscreen rendering.